# find last names in url after # - jquery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get the last names after # in the url in jquery/ javascript

I want to find the names #prices 
and make an if statment

```
if( the_last_name == 'prices' ) 
// do something
```

I need js/jquery to find a way to get urls last name ( and check it on the if statment /the_last_name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
document.location.hash
```

eg:

```
if (document.location.hash == "#prices") {
```

Answer (score 3):

Better, use this:

```
if (document.location.hash.substr(1) == "prices") {
```

so you don't have the '#' in your string.

Comment: why not use the *other* way so don't have `.substr(1)` in your code? 1 extra char vs 10.